# Verificar se um valor está presente em um array

Tags: php, html, array

Eu tenho uma tabela na minha base de dados com vários números. Eu pego os números da base de dados, guardo num `array`, e faço `echo` numa tabela em PHP:

```
echo "<table class='CSSTableGenerator'>";

echo "<tr>";

echo "<th>array</th>";

echo "<th>1</th>";
echo "<th>2</th>";
echo "<th>3</th>";
echo "<th>4</th>";
echo "<th>5</th>";
echo "<th>6</th>";
echo "<th>7</th>";
echo "<th>8</th>";
echo "<th>9</th>";
echo "<th>10</th>";
echo "<th>11</th>";
echo "<th>12</th>";
echo "<th>13</th>";
echo "<th>14</th>";
echo "<th>15</th>";
echo "<th>16</th>";
echo "<th>17</th>";
echo "<th>18</th>";
echo "<th>19</th>";
echo "<th>20</th>";
echo "<th>21</th>";
echo "<th>22</th>";
echo "<th>23</th>";
echo "<th>24</th>";
echo "<th>25</th>";
echo "<th>26</th>";
echo "<th>27</th>";
echo "<th>28</th>";
echo "<th>29</th>";
echo "<th>30</th>";

echo "</tr>";

while ($produto = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {
    $vetor=array($produto['id'],$produto['n1'],$produto['n2'],$produto['n3'],$produto['n4'],$produto['n5'],$produto['e1'],$produto['e2']);

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>".$vetor[1]."&nbsp";
    echo $vetor[2]."&nbsp";
    echo $vetor[3]."&nbsp";
    echo $vetor[4]."&nbsp";
    echo $vetor[5]."&nbsp";
    echo $vetor[6]."&nbsp";
    echo $vetor[7] . "</td>&nbsp";


    for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
        echo '<td class="'.(($vetor[1]==$i) ? 'paint_me_green' : 'paint_me_red').'"></td>';

    }

    echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Os números (*array*) são escritos na coluna `<th>array<th>` e nas outras `<th>1` até `50 <th>` eu gostaria de verificar se os números contidos num dos meus *arrays* por ex: array 10 12 23 10 223. Se o número 10 existir neste `array` a `<th>10</th>` ira ser verde na linha desse `array`, caso contrario vermelha.

Até agora como podem ver no meu código, dentro do `while` e coloquei um `for`

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
    echo '<td class="'.(($vetor[1]==$i) ? 'paint_me_green' : 'paint_me_red').'"></td>';
}
```

mas desta forma ele só está verificando se:

- a posição [1] == 1 ele pinta verde se não pinta vermelho.
- a posição [1] == 2 ele pinta verde se não pinta vermelho.
- ...
- a posição [1] == 23 ele pinta verde se não pinta vermelho.

E funciona desta forma... é o que eu quero. Só que quero fazer o mesmo para as restantes posições além da posição `[1]`.

O `for` que estou a utilizar, não deverá ser a maneira mais correta de analisar as restantes posições.

Seria algo deste gênero que eu precisaria:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
    echo '<td class="'.(($vetor[1]==$i) and ($vetor[2]==$i) and ($vetor[3]==$i) and ($vetor[4]==$i) and and ($vetor[5]==$i) and ($vetor[7]==$i) ? 'paint_me_green' : 'paint_me_red').'"></td>';
}
```

Falaram me no `foreach ($array_de_arrays ...` só não estou conseguir aplicar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa da função [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {
    echo '<td class="'.(in_array($i, $vetor) ? 'paint_me_green' : 'paint_me_red').'"></td>';
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/dH08SQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wgelgnaz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/HTMLConditional.php).

Comment: ele está funcionando como eu queria de acordo com a sua solução. Mas dessa forma, ele vai incrementando um campo verde a mais na linha, até 50 arrays exibidos na tabela. depois funciona normal, valida apenas os 7 elementos do array, sem incrementar nada a mais na linha.

Comment: Você precisa explicar melhor o que quer, qual o resultado que quer. Seus textos são confusos e não dá para entender o que quer.

Comment: Tem razão é um pouco confusa a minha explicação. Pode dar uma olhada na imagem? Ele acrescenta um verde a mais durante 50 arrays na tabela. Depois corre normal
http://imageshack.com/a/img537/1525/dPdnVJ.png

Comment: O problema está em outro lugar, este código está fazendo o certo, talvez você não queira colocar o ID do produto no vetor como você está fazendo mais acima. Faça o teste, tire ele para ver. Depois você decide se quer manter ou não. Aparentemente ele não tem utilidade. Não é só o texto que é confuso, o código também. É muito difícil analisá-lo.

Comment: coloquei 0 na posição desnecessária do id do vetor que vinha da base de dados. Ficou perfeito! @bigown obrigado!